# VideoView in fragment has no sound when played android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-videoview

Hei, 
I am new to android programming and i came upon a problem that i wasn't able solve on my own.

This question isn't new here, and their is alot of good answers out there. But none for the answers i have come upon has worked for me so far. So that's why i posted this question again to find out if there is any other solution beside the ones that you can find here in stackoverflow.

**Here is my xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
              tools:context="com.example.skolen.studentbudsjett.Fragments.EconomyFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_calculator_name"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textHeader"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/textHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCoachAdvice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15sp"
        android:text="@string/textCoachAdvice"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoCoachMadde"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my code**

```
private void initViews(View view) {
        mTextAdvice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCoachAdvice);
        mTextEconomyHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textHeader);
        mVideoEconomy = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoCoachMadde);

    }

    private void initVideo() {
    mMediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
    mMediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoEconomy);

    String video = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sparing;
    Uri mUri = Uri.parse(video);
    mVideoEconomy.setMediaController(mMediaController);
    mVideoEconomy.setVideoURI(mUri);
    mVideoEconomy.requestFocus();
    mVideoEconomy.start();
    mVideoEconomy.setZOrderOnTop(true);

    mVideoEconomy.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        }
    });
}
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: post your code here instead of and image of your code

Comment: It's my first question here.. tried out to see how it would look, but everything should be fine by now

Answer (score 0):

Why set volume to 0... set it by calling `audiomanager`:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Hope this help:

```
audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

For Volume UP:

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

for Volume Down:

```
audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to implement it with my code?